# Updating PyQt5 GUI with Live Data Tablewwidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I created a PyQt5 using QtDesigner and converted it to Python.I got stacked on click function, its supposed to add row info,but the issue is the app didnot refresh data, I need to click each cell to update data. What should I need to change to refresh the data well

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):

```
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "批量划扣"))
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.thread)

def thread(self):
    t1=Thread(target=self.operation)
    t1.start()


def operation(self):
    row=0    
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(user_data))
    for i in range(len(user_data)):
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(customerName[i]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(koukuan(appidnum[i],bankopen[i],bankcard[i],amt[i],overDueMoney[i],overduePi[i],fileMark[i],attachment[i],overduePrincipal[i],overdueInterest[i])))
        time.sleep(1.5)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,2,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(chenggong(casenum[i])))
        row=row+1
        app.processEvents()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use external threads to handle pyqt UI..

Instead use `QThread` and `signal/slot` to send data to UI and update it upon new received data